# How to iterate and erase from TBB concurrent_hash_map C++

Tags: c++, loops, thread-safety, erase

Lets say I have a TBB concurrent_hash_map defined like this:

```
tbb::concurrent_hash_map<int, void*> TbbHash;
```

Now I want to run on all elements in TbbHash safely.

If I would use std::map I would implement it like this:

```
auto it = mymap.begin();
while(it != mymap.end())
{
    delete it->second;
    m.erase(it++);
}
```

What is the right implementation (and thread-safe) for TBB concurrent_hash_map?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, because the tbb `concurrent_hash_map` does not provide thread-safe iterators. The `concurrent_unordered_map` does provide thread-safe iterators, but unfortunately it does not provide a thread-safe erase function.

I can only refer you to other libraries with concurrent data structures like libcds or my own one called [xenium](https://github.com/mpoeter/xenium).